# What does dojo.empty() / domConstruct.empty() do exactly

Tags: javascript, dojo

Let's say I register some widgets with some ids(let's say id1, id2) in `someNode`. Now if I do, `domConstruct.empty(someNode)`, this will remove the widgets from `someNode` by doing `someNode.innerHTML= ""`. But are the widgets still in memory?

What I mean to say is, after `domConstruct.empty(someNode)`, will I be able to register a widget with id1 or id2?

If not, then how can I achieve the same? I do not want to check for widget with same id during its creation and destroy it if it exists.

P.S: I am assuming that `dojo.empty()` and `domConstruct.empty()` work in the same way.

Comment: take a look at the documentation/ or better to google it.

Comment: I have already read the documentation, it says that the children are deleted but the node is kept. But I tried to get a widget by id after `domConstruct.empty()` but I am still getting the widget. Why so?

Comment: Is this essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425204/how-to-remove-dojo-widgets-by-registered-by-id-but-not-referenced-in-any-dom-no?

Comment: @KenFranqueiro: Not exactly. Although, the context is the same. But here I really want to know about the functionality of `domConstruct.empty` and verify if I am right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo/dom-construct`'s APIs do not know anything about Dijit widgets, so when you run `domConstruct.empty(node)` or `domConstruct.destroy(node)`, it does nothing to look for and destroy widgets.  (I've [explained how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433348/237950) in a largely-related question.)

When Dijit widgets are created, they are populated in a hash maintained by the `dijit/registry` module, which allows them to be accessed by ID (or node) in the future.  `dijit/registry.findWidgets` is also used by `dijit/_WidgetBase#getChildren` (which is in turn used by container and layout widgets) to retrieve child widgets according to the DOM tree.

Since `dojo/dom-construct` knows nothing of Dijit, it simply destroys all DOM nodes underneath the given node, and doesn't update Dijit's registry.  Thus, you end up with an inconsistent state, where Dijit thinks these widgets still exist, but their DOM has actually been destroyed.  As answered in the other question, you should use `findWidgets` to properly destroy the widgets first, or consider using a layout widget or `ContentPane` to manage the child widgets for you.

Comment: Thank you! :) I was thinking the same, but I wanted to verify its functionality. Your other answer was also very helpful.